# How do I solve this error message: unlockFocus called too many time

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyside

I am experimenting with the PySide Python module for GUI development. I wrote this small piece of code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit('test text')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

It doesn't look very complicated but it gives me the following message in the terminal when running the code:

```
2015-08-10 20:54:33.066 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:33.068 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:33.560 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:33.561 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:34.055 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:34.055 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:34.554 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:34.555 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:35.055 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:35.056 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:35.556 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
2015-08-10 20:54:35.557 Python[430:f07] unlockFocus called too many time.
```

The list with this message is getting longer and longer while the code is running. When I add a QPushButton, Python stops throwing up the error while the push button has focus. When changing the focus back again to the QLineEdit, the messages are popping up again. Also the blue stroke/border around the textfield (QLineEdit) is expanding and expanding while the messages/errors are showing up.

I'm using python 2.7.10 and PySide 1.2.2 and running this on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Is there something wrong in my code or is it related to something else?

---

Edit:

## After updating my OS...

...to Mac OS X 10.10.4 the messages are gone.
The blue stroke/border around the text field is still growing/getting darker blue while typing. See the screen-shots below:

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like an OSX bug. A websearch on the error description brings up dozens of similar issues. If you can't upgrade your os, you may be stuck with it. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Thanks. I will give my os an upgrade and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: I updated my question above after upgrading my OS as @ekhumoro mentioned.